# SQL Server: reset identity on any delete action

Tags: sql-server, identity, dbcc

Let's take a simple example. There's a table named *test*:

[image]

Now I'm gonna delete some data without reset the identity log:

[image]

When I insert new data, the new id will be 7:

[image]

I'd like that on every delete query the DBCC CHECKIDENT function was automatically called to reset the identity on table test. So, when I'd insert 'Purple', its id would be 4. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why you want do that?  That work if you delete the last ones, but what happen if you delete `2` ... you reset to `2` and then will get duplicate key error when try to insert `3`.

Comment: Juan is right. But, supposing you check first if it was the last value that was deleted, you can achieve your goal using a trigger.

Comment: Don't get hung up on gaps in an identity value. It is normal and expected. What you want to happen if you delete ID 4?

Comment: No, i'd like the identity log would be reset to the last (max) id, not to the one that was just deleted.

Comment: If you do this, you may want to find a way to block other processes.  For example, the query could acquire an application lock or a table lock on the table.  Without any concurrency protection, someone could insert a new row in between the time you looked for the current maximum identity and the point at which you are going to set the new identity value.

Comment: If you care about the *numerical* values of an identity column, you're probably doing something wrong. You should just treat them as opaque binary blobs that happen to fit in numeric columns. Anything else is setting yourself up for pain in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DELETE TRIGGER` and then use

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/PMV84867)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
    ON dbo.test
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @maxID int;

    SELECT @maxID = MAX(id)
    FROM test;

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (test, RESEED, @maxID);
GO
```

So next insert will use 4.

[image]

But again this isnt something you should really be worry about it

Comment: What would happen when multiple rows affected while deleting

Comment: @StackUser Not sure if you saw the fiddle demo, but there I delete `where id >3` and still id reset to max id value.